# Tauri | Download/copy a file in production

Tags: javascript, windows, rust, tauri

I have the following tauri command for general file copying:

```rust
// main.rs
#[tauri::command]
fn copy_file(source: &str, destination: &str) {
    match std::fs::copy(source, destination.to_owned()) {
        Ok(_) => println!("Ok"),
        Err(err) => println!("{}", err),
    };
}
```

And this function in the frontend side.

```js
async function downloadTemplate() {
    const destination = await scripts.handleSelectFolder("Select folder")
    const fullDestination = destination + "\\template.xlsx";
    const source = ".\\src\\assets\\template.xlsx";
    await invoke('copy_file', { source, destination: fullDestination });    
    // openDirectory calls a Tauri command too to open a folder
    await openDirectory(destination);
}
```

The flow is for copying a file called `template.xlsx` from the project folders to the desired user selection.

The template.xlsx in the project is located under:

```
frontend_project_files...
...
src-tauri/
    src/
        main.rs
        assets/
           diot_template.xlsx
```

This implementation works perfectly in development, but in production, no file is copied but the folder opens up correctly.

Im using MSI to install my application, and the installation folder look like this:
[image]

I think the problem might be that the command expects to be an specific path to the `template.xslx` folder but the installed executable does not have any sibling folders.

I might be doing the wrong approach to copy/download files from the app to the user system.

I only want to copy a file to a desired folder in a production bundle.

Answer (score -1):

For any newcomer having the same issue, my problem was solved by only adding this configuration into the tauri.config.

https://tauri.app/v1/api/config/#bundleconfig.resources

Then, I took out the assets folder from the src to the root src-tauri folder.

Changed the javascript call to:

```js
const source = ".\\assets\\diot_template.xlsx";
```

And now, it is working.